# Is it "mockup" or "mock-up" as a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, titles

I work in design and regularly use "mockups". These are templates that let me see what my design will look like.

I know that "mockup" is widely accepted as a noun, but what is the correct verb from these options for a heading:

1. Mockup Your Designs Using Our Mockups
2. Mock-up Your Designs Using Our Mockups
3. Mock-Up Your Designs Using Our Mockups (capitalized U)

Comment: It's *mock up*. Two words. Otherwise, you find yourself saying *I mockupped my design*, which sounds horrendous.

Comment: To continue Peter Shor's point, you could draw an analogy to (probably) more obviously incorrect forms like: *I lookupped the word*, *the traffic buildupped behind the crash*, *cowboys roundupped the cattle*, *we setupped the presentation*

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mock-up (read the whole entry)

Comment: Hyphens are not pronounced, so it doesn't matter how you spell it